# Change variable value in js from HTML JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, file, variables

I need the community to help me with the following:

I defined the variable `x=1` in my js file. I have 2 HTML files that use that variable (*1.html* and *2.html*). I want to use `onclick` event in *1.html* to change the value of variable `x` to `2` permanently.. so that if I use `x` variable in *2.html* it's value is `2` not `1`.

This is what I have in *java.js* file:

```
x=1;
```

This is in *1.html*:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="java.js">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="Change x" onClick="x=4">
            <p id="iz"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is in *2.html*:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="java.js">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="Change x" onClick="x=x+1">
            <p id="iz"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

The result of the button in *2.html* should be `5`.

Comment: The only way to do this would be to pass the values from page to page, which is best done using sessions when x is changed in one page, so that it can be persisted between pages.  You could also use local storage or cookies and load 'x' from those values if present and fallback to its value of '1' if it's not present.

Comment: Can you please example the code that I can use to persist the value between pages? I am using a frameset with 2 cols.. meaning I always have 2 html files open. If this makes things easier to understand I shall go into detail: I am trying to realise a game. For this my index is split in two frames, 1 being the map where you can click on buildings, the other being used for building properties and actions. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd suggest, for now, then, learning specifically about cookies (perhaps using this: http://code.google.com/p/cookies/) as a first-step.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript doesn't work like that. There's no persistence between pages without using cookies, or passing the state to the server.

If you navigate to `foo.html` and it sets `var foo = 1` and then navigate to `bar.html`, `foo` will not have been set.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, you can't only using `JavaScript` - the web is `stateless`.

Though, can use a `cookie` or `local storage` as your backing store to hold the value. Initially setting it to `1`, any subsequent modifications effect the backing store and reflect the proper value.

Answer (score 0):

In java script there is no persistence of variable as you want, you have to use cookies, a server side aproach or the local storaged offered in html5

Answer (score 0):

This is not normal behaviour for JavaScript because the values you set will on persist for the duration of either page. What you probably want to do is store the value of x on a server, store it in a cookie, or store it in localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

In each of your pages it is pulling in `x=1`. Just because you change a variable on one page doesn't mean it is going to be seen on another page. This is where you need to pass variables along to the other pages with either `GET` or `POST` or cookies or local storage

Comment: I will try this first as I do not yet know how to use cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Your input tags are not closed, that can't be right. Fix these before looking for other reasons for bugs in your code:

```
<input type="button" value="Change x" onClick="x=4">
```

Should perhaps be:

```
<input type="button" value="Change x" onClick="x=4"/>
```